# Angular + Ng2 Charts: Chart not displaying as Child Component

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to learn ng2-charts with Angular with the project currently I'm working on.

So basically, I tried out first with a fresh angular project, installed ng2-charts
`npm i ng2-charts chart.js`

I'm trying to achieve it by passing the data to the child component.
Now I'm wondering why my chart (child component) does not display anything.

[image: Empty Page]

The code goes like this.

**Chart Component // sample-chart.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-sample-chart",
  templateUrl: "./sample-chart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./sample-chart.component.css"],
})
export class SampleChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() barChartData;
  @Input() barChartLabels;
  @Input() barChartOptions;
  @Input() barChartPlugins;
  @Input() barChartLegend;
  @Input() barChartType;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.barChartData, "data");
  }
}
```

**Chart Component // sample-chart.component.html**

```
<canvas
  baseChart
  [datasets]="barChartData"
  [labels]="barChartLabels"
  [options]="barChartOptions"
  [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
  [legend]="barChartLegend"
  [chartType]="barChartType"
>
</canvas>
```

**App Component // .ts file**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "app";

  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: { xAxes: [{}], yAxes: [{}] },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: "end",
        align: "end",
      },
    },
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = [
    "2006",
    "2007",
    "2008",
    "2009",
    "2010",
    "2011",
    "2012",
  ];
  public barChartType: ChartType = "bar";
  public barChartLegend = true;

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: "Series A" },
    { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: "Series B" },
  ];
}
```

**App Component // .html file**

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <h1>Welcome to {{ title }}!</h1>

  <div style="display: block">
    <app-sample-chart
      [barChartData]="barChartData"
      [barChartLabels]="barChartLabels"
      [barChartOptions]="barChartOptions"
      [barChartPlugins]="barChartPlugins"
      [barChartLegend]="barChartLegend"
      [barChartType]="barChartType"
    >
    </app-sample-chart>
  </div>

  <!-- <router-outlet></router-outlet> -->
</div>
```

Here is the version used if it's relevant.

**Chart & ng2-charts version used**

```
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: In console any error is displayed?

Comment: If not then can you please check ChartsModule is imported in app.module.ts?

Comment: @AmanGojariya, yes no error displayed. Am getting the data passed as `@Input()`.

Comment: @AmanGojariya, yeah already did that. `imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, ChartsModule],`

Comment: Can you please look into this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template?

Comment: In this demo bar chart is working properly

Comment: I forgot to mention but yeah with that approach the 'chart' will be displayed. Am trying to do it with parent-child component approach.

Comment: Please remove display block div into app.component and add in chart component.html

Comment: I have posted the answer. Please mark is right if it's working for you

Comment: Thank you sir for the suggestion, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try with below code?

**sample-chart.component.html**

```
<div style="display: block;">
   <canvas
     baseChart
     [datasets]="barChartData"
     [labels]="barChartLabels"
     [options]="barChartOptions"
     [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
     [legend]="barChartLegend"
     [chartType]="barChartType"
   >
   </canvas>
</div>
```

You are forgot to add display block div. Can you please try with this in your chart.component.html

Comment: Ooh I see now, that works. I mistakenly added the `display: block` in the app.component

Comment: Thank you sir for the suggestion, much appreciated.

Comment: will take note on that. again Thank you!